# Why std:: setw and std::hex not appropriate of code below?

Tags: c++

I had been seeing some code snippet from someone as shown below:
before changed:

```
  void pal::type3_message::debug_print(std::ostream & out) const
     {
       out << "### type3_message:" << '\n'
           << pal::as_hex_dump(as_bytes())
           << "lm_response = " << pal::as_hex_string(lm_response_)
           << "\nnt_response = " << pal::as_hex_string(nt_response_)
           << "\ndomain = " << domain_
           << "\nuser = "   << user_
           << "\nworkstation = " << workstation_
           << "\nsession_key = " << pal::as_hex_string(session_key_)
           << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0')
           <<"\nssp_flags = " << ssp_flags_;
     }
```

after changed:

```
std::string pal::type3_message::debug_print() const
{
   std::ostringstream buf;
   buf << "### type3_message:" << '\n'
       << pal::as_hex_dump(as_bytes())
       << "lm_response = " << pal::as_hex_string(lm_response_)
       << "\nnt_response = " << pal::as_hex_string(nt_response_)
       << "\ndomain = " << domain_
       << "\nuser = "   << user_
       << "\nworkstation = " << workstation_
       << "\nsession_key = " << pal::as_hex_string(session_key_)
       << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0')
       <<"\nssp_flags = " << ssp_flags_;
    return buf.str();
}
```

I am not very sure of the change above, is anyone can tell me how that should happened and the deep significance of it ? look forward for response and appreciate of it.

Comment: Your post is unclear, exactly what are you asking?

Comment: the difference between the two code snippet is that "do not mess with borrowed things" from someone advice.code shown as of after changed is better. in another word i can't read and understand the meaning of "do not mess with borrowed things" which is the reason to change from which code before changed to which code after changed.

Comment: You have not made it any clearer.  Also you should amend your original post not post multiple replies (all saying the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, so I'm just explaining what the code sample does and what the major difference between both functions is:

> ```
> void pal::type3_message::debug_print(std::ostream & out) const
> ```

This function **writes a message to an output stream** that is referenced by the `out` parameter. It has no return value.

> ```
> std::string pal::type3_message::debug_print() const
> ```

This function seems to output the same message but instead of writing it to a stream, it **stores the message in a string**. This string is returned by the function.

The implementation of both functions looks very similar because the 2nd function uses a temporary `std::ostringstream` internally. This is a stream that exist **in memory only**. In contrast, you could pass a file stream like `std::ofstream` to the 1st function.

Please clarify your question if you want to know more.

Comment: the difference between the two code snippet is that "do not mess with borrowed things" from someone advice.code shown as of after changed is better. in another word i can't read and understand the meaning of "do not mess with borrowed things" which is the reason to change from which code before changed to which code after changed.

Answer (score 0):

> can tell me how that should happened and the deep significance of it?

The first method receives an std::ostream& parameter, and streams more than 10 different chunks of text into it.

The second method streams the same 10 chunks of text into a locally created (automatic var) std::ostringstream.  This concatenates the chunks prior to returning the string.

Possible usage examples (to achieve same output on std::cout):

```
pal::type3_message::debug_print(std::cout);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

and

```
std::cout << pal::type3_message::debug_print() << std::endl;
```

I prefer the std::stringstream approach, but I have used both.

---

In the first method, the thread can be 'interrupted' in more places (between the 10) with possible impact to the not private stream effort. Does this cause an issue?  I have not investigate on a desktop.

The second method completes the concatenation, then returns a string.  All the previous interruption points are still there, but none affect the delivery to std::cout, a shared stream destination.  Note there is still 1 (or maybe 2) interruptions places in this path (to append the string).  Still, this is probably less likely to produce visible issues.

---

In an embedded system I once worked on, because of drivers it had, the second method was clearly better (in terms of thread interruptions during use) and appeared it did not need mutex guard on the out channel.

---

On Ubuntu, I have added mutex guard's to access std::cout ... to avoid the 'inter-mixed' text, though I did not confirm that the change-described-in-this-post could have been sufficient.

---

I have an in-ram-log with a round-robin-buffer, and that shared resource has a mutex guard.  Never any problems with multiple threads contributing to the same log.

---

Note: Per the post Question, I see no difference in either stream effort with respect to std::hex or std::setw, both are used identically.

---

update per July 2, comment

I agree that 'after' is what I prefer.

I do not recognize the phrase "do not mess with borrowed things". I looked and decided Google's report on this phrase had no software relevance.

But it reminded me of a possibly related caution I have heard, "code is like an onion". The guy who repeated this to me (obsessively) resisted 'fixing' things (a crash for example) because, I surmise, he worried that any changes might break 'behaviour' in an undetectable manner. Thus, he worked through 'all the onion layers' until he was sure nothing bad would happen, before he committed a code change. 'Paralysis by analysis' comes to mind.

I am, apparently, much more tolerant to trying something else (and test, test, test...) That crash was easy to fix, and the crash certainly held up progress on understanding the deeper layers of the onion.

Comment: the difference between the two code snippet is that  "do not mess with borrowed things" from someone advice.code shown as of after changed is better. in another word i can't read and understand the meaning of "do not mess with borrowed things" which is the reason to change from which code before changed to which code after changed.

Comment: @W.Costanza   I agree that 'after' is what I prefer.  I do not recognize the phrase "do not mess with borrowed things".  I looked and decided Google's report on this phrase had no software relevance. But it reminded me of a possibly related caution I have heard, "code is like an onion".  The guy who repeated this to me (obsessively) resisted 'fixing' things (a crash for example) because, I surmise, he worried that any changes might break 'behaviour' in an undetectable manner.  I am, apparently, much more tolerant to trying something else (and test, test, test...)  That crash was easy to fix.

Comment: Thanks, Douglas! You really gotcha what I had wonder way to about the original question post.